# When to use the Using statement

Tags: .net, vb.net, filestream, using-statement

I think I may be using the Using statement wrong here. What would be a better way of writing this?

```
Dim x As New Serialization.XmlSerializer( ... )
Using file As New FileStream(myFile, FileMode.Create)
   Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(file)
      x.Serialize(writer, myCollection)
   End Using
End Using
```

I've read that you're only supposed to use a `using` block on objects that have a `.Dispose()` (i.e. implements IDisposable), which is why I'm thinking there shouldn't be a Using on "writer", but instead a `writer.Close()` at the end. But "file" has both a `.Dispose()` and a `.Close()`, so which do I use? The `using` or `file.Close()`?

Note: I'm using an XmlWriter because I can customize the output. I removed the settings here, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both `FileStream` and `XmlWriter` implement `IDisposable` - the code is correct. Actually the compiler probably wouldn't let you do this if it was wrong. If there isn't a public `.Dispose()`, then it must be using *explicit interface implementation* - but that doesn't change your responsibility for calling `.Dispose()`. For interest, in C# you can avoid the ever-increasing nesting/indenting, i.e.

```
using(...a...)
using(...b...)
using(...c...)
{
   ...
}
```

but fundamentally your current code is correct.

Comment: I would, however, recommend adding a `writer.Flush()` statement after the `Serialize()`. Stream writers are notorious for not writing your last batch of buffered data if you don't explicitly flush them.

Comment: @Toby - I'd rather call Close() personally; in particlar, with GZipStream etc, even Flush() doesn't properly flush. You need to close or dispose (it works in this case) to get the last few bytes.

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't `.Dispose()` call `.Close()` (like Hans Passant said), which calls `.Flush()`? So wouldn't a Using take care of all of these?

Comment: @grantman - that is an implementation detail ;p *hopefully* is the best answer I can give...

Comment: For interest, you can [also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) avoid the heavy indentation in VB like this `Using a As New blah, b As New blah`

Comment: @MarkJ thanks; I wouldn't have guessed that syntax. My vb.net is *mainly* read-only, perhaps to my shame.

Comment: @Marc One of the areas where VB is less verbose than C# ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed confusing and has been the subject of much debate.  This is the implementation of the Dispose() method:

```
Public Sub Dispose()
    Me.Close
End Sub
```

In other words, calling Dispose() does the *exact same thing* as calling Close().  You definitely want to take advantage of the Using statement here.

Comment: Thanks! So basically just use Using whenever possible (esp. when dealing with streams)?

Comment: Using Close() makes sense if you open a file and close it some time later in another method.  Which is basically why it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `.Close` *and* `.Dispose` issue is a bit unfortunate.

It is (was?) an official MS guideline though. The Close method is called a **Domain Specific Alias**.

And like the word Alias suggests, you may assume that they do exactly the same. Usually Close will just call Dispose.

The `Using ...  End Using` block will only compile with a reference that is IDisposable (has .Dispose)

---

General advice:

- When a Class has a .Dispose, use a`Using` block
- `Using` is just short-hand for `Try ... Finally` and you can fall back on that. But
- Don't get creative trying to combine or economize multiple blocks
- When the nesting gets to deep (> 3..5), factor out an extra method.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. Note that you will get a compile-time error if you attempt to use `using` on a data type that does not support `IDispose`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tend to do both, but that could be because I'm a bit old fashioned.  If I've opened a file (which you have), I'll explicitly close it.  Whether or not the Dispose method does a clean close is up to the implementation of the object, not up to the client.  But, as the object still implements IDisposable you still need to call it.